# Filling missing dates in a sequence while keeping other values in the row in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
ID <- c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","B1","B1","B1","B1")
Age <- c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3)
Date <- c("2006-05-03",NA,"2006-05-05",NA,"2006-05-07","2006-06-02",NA,"2006-06-04","2006-06-05")
Value1 <- c(6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4)

df
  ID Age       Date Value1
1 A1   0 2006-05-03      6
2 A1   1       <NA>      6
3 A1   2 2006-05-05      6
4 A1   3       <NA>      6
5 A1   4 2006-05-07      6
6 B1   0 2006-06-02      4
7 B1   1       <NA>      4
8 B1   2 2006-06-04      4
9 B1   3 2006-06-05      4
```

Each ID has a full sequence of age (days) with different length and I would like to fill the missing dates belong to the age value accordingly. For each ID I always have the first and the last dates.

I tried

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        complete(Date = seq(min(df$Date, na.rm = TRUE), max(df$Date, na.rm = TRUE), by ="days"))
```

which works for the Date but in the meantime overwrites all the other values in that row with NAs.

Is there a solution for filling the Dates and keeping all the other values in the row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `mutate` the `Date` adding the `Age` to the first `Date` of the group:

```r
ID <- c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A1","B1","B1","B1","B1")
Age <- c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3)
Date <- c("2006-05-03",NA,"2006-05-05",NA,"2006-05-07","2006-06-02",NA,"2006-06-04","2006-06-05")
Value1 <- c(6,6,6,6,6,4,4,4,4)

df <- data.frame(ID, Age, Date, Value1)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        mutate(Date = first(as.Date(Date)) + Age)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID      Age Date       Value1
#>   <fct> <dbl> <date>      <dbl>
#> 1 A1        0 2006-05-03      6
#> 2 A1        1 2006-05-04      6
#> 3 A1        2 2006-05-05      6
#> 4 A1        3 2006-05-06      6
#> 5 A1        4 2006-05-07      6
#> 6 B1        0 2006-06-02      4
#> 7 B1        1 2006-06-03      4
#> 8 B1        2 2006-06-04      4
#> 9 B1        3 2006-06-05      4
```

Created on 2018-05-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fill` to replace NAs with last non-NA value, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, '%Y-%m-%d')) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 complete(Date = seq(min(Date, na.rm = TRUE), max(Date, na.rm = TRUE), by = "days")) %>% 
 fill(Age, Value1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 4
> # Groups:   ID [2]
>   ID    Date                  Age Value1
>   <chr> <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl>
> 1 A1    2006-05-03 00:00:00    0.     6.
> 2 A1    2006-05-04 00:00:00    0.     6.
> 3 A1    2006-05-05 00:00:00    2.     6.
> 4 A1    2006-05-06 00:00:00    2.     6.
> 5 A1    2006-05-07 00:00:00    4.     6.
> 6 B1    2006-06-02 00:00:00    0.     4.
> 7 B1    2006-06-03 00:00:00    0.     4.
> 8 B1    2006-06-04 00:00:00    2.     4.
> 9 B1    2006-06-05 00:00:00    3.     4.
> ```